# Prevent DataGridDragDropTarget from Showing "Drag Shadow"

Tags: silverlight, drag-and-drop, silverlight-toolkit

Is it possible to prevent the Silverlight Toolkit DataGridDragDropTarget from starting a drag-action?

What I whant is to use one DataGrid only as DragSource and another one only as DropTarget. And the DropTarget-only-DataGrid should not show this "StartDragShadow" when pressing and moving the mouse over an item.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the `AllowedSourceEffects` attribute of the `toolkit:DataGridDragDropTarget` control   to `"None"`:

```
<toolkit:DataGridDragDropTarget AllowDrop="true" AllowedSourceEffects="None">
   <sdk:DataGrid Name="DropTarget" />
</toolkit:DataGridDragDropTarget>
```