# Silverlight DragDropTarget: replace "drag shadow" with other element?

Tags: silverlight, drag-and-drop, silverlight-toolkit

[image]

When using the Silverlight Toolkit's DragDropTarget, a snapshot of the item being dragged is shown under the cursor.

Is it possible to replace this snapshot/drag shadow or disable it?

Background:
I am dragging items between controls, i.e. from a listbox to a canvas, and when I drop my listbox item I create a different item with different dimensions on the canvas. I want to show the item that is going to be created, or at least its area, instead of the text from the listbox.

[This related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2966724/prevent-datagriddragdroptarget-from-showing-drag-shadow) didn't help me.

Thanks!

edit: [This related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762668/customize-the-look-of-the-silverlight-control-toolkit-drag-drop) suggests changing the source code to change the little "insertion indicator" icons.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue in my application working with dragdroptarget in datagrids, i found a solution but that did not result in desired way. Well due to that solution i be able to figure out another way that work exactly the way i wanted.

I use **DragStarting** event to cancel the drag based on the input i received from **MouseLeftButtonUp** and **MouseLeftButtonDown** Events.

In DragStarting Event:

```
public void dg1stUnAllocDragStarting (object sender, ItemDragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (blnMouseLeftButtonUp)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            e.Handled = true;
        }

        blnMouseLeftButtonUp = false;
    }
```

MouseLeftButtonUp Event:

```
public void dataGrid1stUnAllocChild_MouseLeftButtonUp (object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {           
        blnMouseLeftButtonUp = true;
    }
```

MouseLeftButtonDown Event:

```
public void dataGrid1stUnAllocChild_MouseLeftButtonDown (object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {           
        blnMouseLeftButtonUp = false;
        e.Handled = false;           
    }
```

Hope it will help you.